# combine two array and return one resultset

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here are my two arrays
users array

```
$users = [
[
    'name' => 'Bikash',
    'city_id' => 1
],
[
    'name' => 'Riaz',
    'city_id' => 3
],
[
    'name' => 'Sayantan',
    'city_id' => 2
],
[
    'name' => 'Subha',
    'city_id' => 1
],
[
    'name' => 'Amit',
    'city_id' => 2
]
];
```

Cities Array

```
$cities = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Kolkata'
],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Bangalore'
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Mumbai'
],
];
```

I want city_id to be replaced with city name in user array.

Sample output

```
$users = [
[
'name' => 'Bikash',
'city' => 'Kolkata'
],
[
'name' => 'Riaz',
'city' => 'Mumbai'
],
[
'name' => 'Sayantan',
'city_id' => 'Bangalore'
],
[
'name' => 'Subha',
'city' => 'Kolkata'
],
[
'name' => 'Amit',
'city' => 'Bangalore'
]
];
```

Here is what i have tried so far

```
$userNew = [];

foreach ($users as $user):
  $userNew[$user['name']] = $cities[0]['name'];
endforeach;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($userNew);
```

I couldn't find any solutions for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) functions:

```
$city_names = array_column($cities, 'name', 'id');
array_walk($users, function(&$v, $k) use($city_names){
   if (isset($city_names[$v['city_id']])) {
       $v['city_id'] = $city_names[$v['city_id']];
   }
});

print_r($users);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bikash
            [city_id] => Kolkata
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Riaz
            [city_id] => Mumbai
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sayantan
            [city_id] => Bangalore
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Subha
            [city_id] => Kolkata
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Amit
            [city_id] => Bangalore
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make an array with city id and city name pair. [**Live demo here**](https://eval.in/809972).

```
$map = array_combine(array_column($cities, 'id'), array_column($cities, 'name'));
foreach($users as &$v)
{
  $v['city_id'] = $map[$v['city_id']];
}
```

more clear way to calculate `$map` from [answer of RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322577/6521116)

`$map = array_column($cities, 'name', 'id');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $newCities=array();
  //resort cities, so we can get the values directly
  foreach($cities as $key => $value )
  {
      $newCities[$key]=$value;
  }
  $newUser=array();
  //now we can go over user 
  foreach($user as $key => $value )
  {
     $newData['name']=$value['name'];
     $newData['city']=$newCities[$value['city_id']];
     $newUser[$key]=$newData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the nested loop but than it will be long process.

A better way to do it is:

```
$newCitties = [];
foreach($cities as $city){
    $newCitties[$city['id']] = $city['name'];
}

foreach($users as $user){
    $user['city'] = $newCitties[$user['city_id']];
    unset($user['city_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$newuser = "";
function getCityname($cities,$cityid){

    foreach($cities as $city){
        if($city['id'] == $cityid) return $city['name'];
    }
}

foreach($users as $user){
    $cityname = getCityname($cities,$user['city_id']);
    $newuser[] = array('name' => $user['name'] , 'city' => $cityname);
}

print_r($newuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_cities = array_combine(array_column($cities, 'id'), array_column($cities, 'name'));

$userNew = [];

foreach ($users as $user):
    $userNew[] = ['name' => $user['name'], 'city' => $_cities[$user['city_id']]];
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.